# Package to use for documenting a struct

Tags: packages, pseudocode

There exists a number of pseudo-code packages for LaTeX. Can any of these describe things like a linked-list node in C:

```
struct Node
   {
   Node* parent;
// other stuff
   };
```

or do I have to invent some custom macros

Comment: An algorithm package or just typesetting the code? (`listings`, for example, for the second case)

Comment: ChristianHupfer: The former, otherwise I would have tagged the question differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach with `algorithm2e`. I defined a "program-like" block `MyStruct` that begins with the keyword `Struct`, then typesets the structure name, then outputs keyword `contains`, and the end of the structure is denoted with keyword `end`:

```
\SetKwProg{MyStruct}{Struct}{ contains}{end}
```

All of this can be customized to your heart's content.

Usage within an algorithm is something like:

```
\MyStruct{Node}{
  Node* parent\;
  int size\;
  \tcp{other stuff}
}
```

Here's a complete simple example and output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetKwProg{MyStruct}{Struct}{ contains}{end}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\MyStruct{Node}{
  Node* parent\;
  int size\;
  \tcp{other stuff}
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This definition respects the global package options and also local switches, so you could use for example `[noend,noline]` as package options to disable typesetting of the `end` keyword(s) and the vertical line delimiting the block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend,noline]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetKwProg{MyStruct}{Struct}{ contains}{end}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\MyStruct{Node}{
  Node* parent\;
  int size\;
  \tcp{other stuff}
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't I define a keyword *pointer* so it becomes less C specific?

Comment: You can define whatever you want. You listed almost zero requirements, so as I said, this is just one possible approach.